# Make a JQuery Animation for a fixed time

Tags: jquery

I'm receiving a Json response to a table that I'm rendering and I'm able to specify wich TDs of the table are going to recieve a animation to call the user's attention for some secs.

My TDs are rendered this way:

```
.append($('<td>')
  .addClass('col1 linhaSub changed')
  .text(model.ListView[3][0].Sign)
)
```

By using a `model.ListView[3][0].Effect` as a boolean ( true = put class, false = ignore), I need to make a conditional statement to this TD and create a class with any animation like background changing ( from black to default, idk).

I have found `.toggleClass()` from Jquery but I couldn't make it work. Maybe because of the fact that I need just to change the background or make a simple text  effect on a TD.

Since I'm really new to jquery and CSS I would like some help with this. Some notes:

- I'm using CSS 2.1.
- I will render MANY tds, so less code, better. I'd like to avoid whole TD append on conditional statements.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you appending these with a for loop?

Comment: @realseanp no loops. Its a fixed table with many colspans and rowspans.. Thats why im addressing the object direclty for each line